# getAssetRegistry on parent asset type fails in hyperledger-composer transaction

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When I try to call `getAssetRegistry` inside a transaction on the base class of an asset, on an asset that is inherited from the base, it fails with an error `Object with ID 'poly1' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.model.PolygonMarble' does not exist`

call to `changeOwner(org.acme.model.PolygonMarble#poly1, org.acme.model.Collector#owner2)`

model.cto:

```
namespace org.acme.model

asset Marble identified by Id { 
  o String Id
  --> Collector owner  
}
asset PolygonMarble extends Marble { 
  o Integer sides
}
participant Collector identified by email {
  o String email
}
transaction ChangeOwner {
  --> Marble marble
  --> Collector newOwner
}
```

script.js:

```
/*@param {org.acme.model.ChangeOwner} args - 
* @transaction */
function changeOwner(args) {
  args.marble.owner = args.newOwner;  
  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.model.Marble').then(function(marbleRegistry) {
    return marbleRegistry.update(args.marble);
  });
}
```

This case is not explicited documented, but is it an expected behavior?
It is very different from what is expected of a typical inheritance use case though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given your current TP (as you originally posted) of

```
/*
 * @param {org.acme.model.ChangeOwner} args
 * @transaction
 */

function changeOwner(args) {
  args.marble.owner = args.newOwner;  
  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.model.Marble') 
  .then(function(marbleRegistry) {
  return marbleRegistry.update(args.marble);
  });
}
```

you would (have to) pass in 
    org.acme.model.Marble#marble1, org.acme.model.Collector#owner2

This is because you chose to work with the 'Marble' asset registry in your function. Also your modeled Transaction expects that - that's how you've set it up (ie update the 'Marble' asset registry).

If you want to update the PolyMarble registry then you should:

1) update your model

```
transaction ChangeOwner {
  --> PolygonMarble marble
  --> Collector newOwner
}
```

2) update your code to be:

```
/*@param {org.acme.model.ChangeOwner} args - 
* @transaction */
function changeOwner(args) {
  args.marble.owner = args.newOwner;  
 return getAssetRegistry(args.marble.getFullyQualifiedType())).then(function(marbleRegistry) {
    return marbleRegistry.update(args.marble);
  });
}
```

3) update your deployed business network with the latest model and transaction code above

And finally - obviously, you would pass in (as before):
   org.acme.model.PolygonMarble#poly1, org.acme.model.Collector#owner2

to your transaction and it should work

Comment: am I right to say, it doesn't work like a typical inheritance in other languages, where a method defined on a base class would work automatically in an inherited class?

Comment: the model does observe inheritance yes. See more here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html. It returns a promise and then you can work with the registry. That is what you are doing in your Transaction Processor code. The resource instance you are trying to update is stored in a registry (eg PolygomMarble - this a view into the blockchain if you like) and that's an entirely separate resource registry - to the 'Marble' registry. But any attributes defined in Marble, are required in any PolygonMarble resources (as you have defined it). So it is expected behaviour.

Comment: does the answer above make sense then?

Comment: yes it does. What you're doing, is getting a string (using getFullyQualifiedType() )) of the resource passed in. I will add this as an option to my answer, which validates your added answer (since).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, so I think replacing the hardcoded AssetRegistry class with `getFullyQualifiedType()` worked for me.
One additional step for inherited classes.

```
/*@param {org.acme.model.ChangeOwner} args - 
* @transaction */
function changeOwner(args) {
  args.marble.owner = args.newOwner;  
  return 
getAssetRegistry(args.marble.getFullyQualifiedType()).then(function(marbleRegistry) {
    return marbleRegistry.update(args.marble);
  });
}
```